# Blender Material Preview Transparent Objects Bug (2.91)

Tags: error

[image]

Hello!
I am getting this error in Material Preview mode. Does anyone know?

Comment: Where is the error msg?

Answer (score 0):

This is an AMD Radeon drivers issue. Roll back to July's update (20.7.2) and you'll be back in business.